# can you determine the distinct variable bit packets from within this bitstream?

Tags: computer-science

11001101111011000011000111001011010011010111011011100011100111101011
the above bit stream should break up into these variable bit packets
11 0011 0111 1011 000011 000111 001011 010011 010111 011011 100011 100111
101011
basically it is a base 3 number represented in base 2 as 2 bits base 2 number
of variable length, with a 11 as a stop pattern, as long as you are looking at this 2 bits at a time, can you determine the second list of values from the bit stream I gave at the top part?

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to remember some state between the processing steps, then yes.

Just do the following, assuming that the state bit is $s$ and the current input bits are $b_0$, $b_1$

1. Append $b_0$ to the output
2. If $s \land b_0$

   1. Append space to the output
3. Append $b_1$ to the output
4. If $\lnot s \land b_0 \land b_1$

   1. Append space to the output
   2. Set $s \leftarrow 0$
5. Otherwise

   1. Set $s \leftarrow b_1$

Thus, $s = 1$ if the last bist of the *previous* 2-bit chunk might be the first (but not the second!) bit of a stop pattern. By comparing $s$ and $b_0$, stop pattern which are split between two such chunks are detected and handled appropriately. By comparing $b_0$ and $b_1$, stop patterns within a chunk are detected, and the additional check for $s=0$ ensures that $0111$ isn't decoded to "011 1 " but rather to "011 1". Setting $s$ to $0$ in 4.2 prevents "1110" from being decoded to "11 1 0".

Here's an example. Say the input is $$
  011110001110100110 \text{.}
$$
The processing then does this $$
\begin{array}{cc|ll|ll|ll|ll|ll|ll|ll|ll|ll}
b_0 &b_1                          & 0&1 & 1&1 & 1&0 & 0&0 & 1&1 & 1&0 & 1&0 & 0&1 & 1&0 \\
s_{\textrm{in}} &s_{\textrm{out}} & 0&1 & 1&1 & 1&0 & 0&0 & 0&0 & 0&0 & 0&0 & 0&1 & 1&0 \\
\hline
                                 && 0&1 & 1.&1& 1.&0& 0&0 & 1&1.& 1&0 & 1&0 & 0&1 & 1.&0
\end{array}
$$
where the last line is the output, and dots represent spaces.

Notation-wise, $\lnot$ means logical not, i.e. $\lnot x$ is true if $x=0$, and $\land$ means logical and, i.e. $x \land y$ is true if $x=1$ and $y=1$. Logical or (which isn't used here) would be written as $x \lor y$ and would be true if $x=1$ or $y=1$.

Comment: well thanks, not sure what this symbol ^ means as in: "If s^b0 " in this context, can you enlighten me please?? if I could just get that I Think I can understand the rest.. thanks

Comment: It means "logical and". In other words, $s \land b_0$ is true if $s=1$ and $b_0=1$.

Comment: Btw, you get that symbol with `\land` in LaTex and MathJax

Comment: OK thank you very much, would what you are describing be processing the data one bit at a time?... because the packet size or minimum number of bits would be 2 bits, because you would have to look for the stop bit pattern of 11 , to determine that the end of the pattern has been reached, if you only look at one bit at a time as It would seem your suggestion suggests, what's to prevent it from finding the first "11" pattern that shows up.. such as the decoding of 000111, whats to prevent it from decoding as 00011?? I guess the the fact that 00011 is only 5 bits.

Comment: @JohnEinem Just FYI, I just edited my answers to fix a bug I found upon re-reading it.

Comment: @JohnEinem It *will* decode "000111" as "00011 1", that what your question *says* it should, no? Otherwise, saying that "11" is the *stop-pattern* really doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @JohnEinem It looks at *two* bits at a time, that's why it has *two* inputs $b_0$ and $b_1$. I'll add an example of how it works...

Comment: ok thanks a lot... yeah I must be tired... but there is probably more than one way to do the decoding of this type of bit stream of variable bit length "words" you could look at the whole thing two bits at a time and then add the code to the output buffer for as long as the two bits are not 11 , when it encounters a 11 bit pattern append that to the output , then a space or whatever signals the receiver that a new code is coming, if the first pair of values received is 11 then it is done with a complete "word" or command , and then can send that and signal that a new code is on its way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8943/discussion-between-john-einem-and-fgp)

Comment: @fpg I hate to say it but 011110001110100110 should decode as 0111 100111 010011 with an extra 0 at the end an incomplete code...